# Extract 2nd and 3rd character in a string - SAS

Tags: sas

I have a variable DRG in my dataset and I would like to create a new variable with the second and third characters in the DRG string. For example, if DRG value is A23B I would like to extract 23 as a new variable.

Can someone please help me with the SAS code. Thanks a lot in advance.

Sample code

```
data example;
input DRG $4.;
cards;
A23B
A13A
A45C
B82B
B82C
B34A
C01A
C25B
C46B
;
run;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the text functions SAS has available?  Perhaps one of the questions on the right under Related?

Comment: The term you're looking for is substring. How to extract a substring from a string, in this case use the `substr()` function but bookmarking this page is a good idea https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl//en/lefunctionsref/69762/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0w6napahk6x0an0z2dzozh2ouzm.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help.
I was able to work out the answer by following this webpage https://www.listendata.com/2017/03/extract-last-4-characters-digits-in-sas.html

Here is my code:

```
data example2;
set example;
want = substr(DRG,length(DRG)-2,2);
run;
```

Comment: I would have expected to see this: `substr(DRG, 2, 2)`

Comment: Your code is straight forward, I was using a long method. Both have the same output. Thank you.